# IIS AppPool configured to use .NET Framework 4.0 is still using 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, application-pool

I have to run an ASP.NET application that uses .NET 4.0, so I created a new Web Site in IIS Manager (inetmgr.exe) and set its Application Pool to ASP.NET v4.0, here is a screenshot with the description of the AppPool:

[image: AppPool configuration]

Here is a screenshot of how i configurated the web site:

[image: WebSite configuration]

But when I navigate to the website i get this error

[image: Navigation error]

In english is

> Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names
>   are case-sensitive.

This error happens when you run an ASP.NET 4.0 application in 2.0 AppPool, and from the screenshot you can also notice

> .NET Framework:2.0.50727.5456

Why is it running .NET 2.0? What am I doing wrong in my configuration?
I also tried `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` even for .NET 4.0 and 2.0, but without success

Comment: @CodeCaster Look at the first screen shot: the app pool is set to .Net V4

Comment: Normally that missing attribute is only used to mark as requiring v4.5 or later (and it was added with .NET 4,5). You get that error with .NET 4 app pool when a later version of .NET has not been installed.

Comment: @Richard Thanks, the problem was the attribute, I removed it(it was useless) and it works, I'm still wondering why it claim to be running .NET Framework:2.0.50727.5456, but it doesn't matter at all. If you post an answer I will be pleased to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

That appears with .NET 4 when a later version (eg. 4.5.2) is not installed. The attribute is added in .NET 4.5 (so the ASP.NET loader knows to load a later version of the 4 series).

If you do not have .NET 4.5 or later installed the loader doesn't know what to do with that attribute.

(.NET 4.5.2 has been pushed out on Windows Updates: IMHO servers really should be running at least that version by now: it contains significant bug fixes over .NET 4. Particularly so if new web apps are being deployed.)

I assume the V2 appearing on the YSOD is due to fallback having failed to load under .NET 4.